# Replace spaces with Regex without replacing empty HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wish to replace spaces in something like this:

`<span>5</span>SPACE<image href="mtgsymbol.png" />`

but when I do so using:

`card_cost=card_cost.replace(/\s/g,"");`

it messes my css all up and the objects stack on each other like their position is changed to absolute.

How do I replace the spaces without breaking my css or document flow?

Example code:

Javascript:

```
card_cost=document.getElementById('card_cost').value;

if(card_cost)
{
card_cost=card_cost.replace(/\d+/g,"<span class='card_costnum'>$&</span>");
*breaks styling*card_cost=card_cost.replace(/\s/g,"");*breaks styling*
}

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML+="<div class='card'>"+"<span class='card_cost'>"+card_cost+"</span>";
```

CSS:

```
.card_name,.card_image,.card_cost,.card_type,.card_subtype,.card_rarity,.card_rules,.card_flavor,.card_strength,.card_num,.card_lower,.card_costnum
{
position:relative;
z-index:1;
}

.card_cost
{
display:inline-block;
float:right;
clear:right;
}

.card_costnum
{
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
background-image:url("numsymbol_small.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:12px;
height:12px;
margin:1px;
top:-4px;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand - what is it you're trying to do? (I tried answering, but looking back, I'm not sure it's what you need anymore.)

Comment: Use DOM manipulation to remove whitespace text nodes instead of regex. And don't do `.innerHTML+=...`. It's a terrible thing to do to your DOM.

Comment: If you tie to minimize your css you can also remove all new lines and `"` in the url, etc. have a look at http://www.codebeautifier.com/

Comment: The html doesn't match javascript in your example.

Comment: Whoever posted about positioning the space replacement before any other replacements that fixed my issue.

Comment: @Event_Horizon: That really fixed the issue? Okay, I'll undelete it then...

Comment: @minitech Yeah it did, the problem was that it was messing up all of my other regex's I was using to insert tags into the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
card_cost = card_cost.replace(/\d+/g, "<span class='card_costnum'>$&</span>");
card_cost = card_cost.replace(/\s/g, "");
```

You're turning it into `<spanclass='card_costnum'>`, which is not valid, and which will break the rest of your HTML. Just reverse the replacements.

```
card_cost = card_cost.replace(/\s/g, "");
card_cost = card_cost.replace(/\d+/g, "<span class='card_costnum'>$&</span>");
```